# C++ build boost 1.57.0 VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt

Tags: c++, boost

After launching build with

```
b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=release threading=multi link=shared
```

I see `...found 600 targets...`

> E:\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0\tools\build>b2 toolset=msvc-12.0
>   variant=release threading=multi link=shared ...found 600 targets...
>
> E:\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0\tools\build>

Any directory `staged/libs` does not appear in `boost_1_57_0` folder? What I am doing wrong? How to build lib files?

**Update**

after `bjam --toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete --prefix=D:\Boost install`
i see only result output in console `...found 819 targets...` What means found? I do npt see any .lib files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Steps given in this url (simpler):
https://theboostcpplibraries.com/introduction-installation (can be used for linux and windows)

An alternate URL(for unix and linux):
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Both shared and static library can be created easily by the above URLs steps.
Note: Library is located in /usr/local/lib in your system.